# How can I add audio to a rolling air hockey puck in Unity2D (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an air hockey game in Unity and I want the puck to sound like it's rolling across the canvas. I also want the sound to match the movement of the ball (get slower when the ball is slowing down, etc.) I searched for tutorials on this but I haven't found any good for C# and I've been struggling for days. I'm new to Unity and C#, so I'm not familiar with all functions and statements.

Comment: Simplest way would be to have a single sound and change its pitch depending on its speed.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on this? Not sure how to go about this. Code I currently have isn't working.

Comment: Just google it there are plenty of tutorials around for Unity it's one of its most redeeming features.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is as @akaBase said in the comments.

First, you'll want to get a good and loopable sound.

Second, you add an audio source component to the puck object and put the sound clip in.

Third, you need to make a script that looks at the current speed of the puck. If it's being moved by physics you can just request **rigidbody.velocity** every **FixedUpdate** or **Update** to change the **audioSource.pitch**.

Give it a try. Should be easy enough to figure out from here. You'll need to experiment a bit to see what sounds best, but if you still need help, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example script for changing pitch depending on the current speed of an object. Feel free to modify it - change the Update method to a FixedUpdate if you're gonna use physics, change how the speed is calculated/acquired etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementBasedPitchAdjuster : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSource = null;
    public float pitchAdjustingFrequency = 0.5f;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float maxPitch = 1f;

    private float speed = 0f;
    private Vector3 lastRecordedPosition;
    private float traveledDistance = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartAdjustingPitchAndSpeed());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        RecordTraveledDistance();
    }

    private IEnumerator StartAdjustingPitchAndSpeed()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            UpdateSpeed();
            AdjustPitch();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(pitchAdjustingFrequency);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSpeed()
    {
        float newSpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(traveledDistance);
        speed = newSpeed > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : newSpeed;
        
        traveledDistance = 0f;
    }

    private void AdjustPitch()
    {
        audioSource.pitch = speed / maxSpeed * maxPitch;
    }

    private void RecordTraveledDistance()
    {
        traveledDistance += Vector3.Distance(
            lastRecordedPosition,
            transform.position);
        
        lastRecordedPosition = transform.position;
    }
}
```

A test using an object that follow the cursor position.
https://streamable.com/fkw0k2